# MonoTouch.Dialog StyledStringElement

Tags: xamarin.ios, element, monotouch.dialog, xamarin

Hy guys!

How can I set / access the DetailTextLabel of a StyledStringElement in MonoTouch.Dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the second argument is the detail text value.  Note that you have to specify a cell style (third argument) that supports the detailed text - the default cell style does not display a detail text value.

```
new StyledStringElement ("Default", "Invisible value", UITableViewCellStyle.Default),
new StyledStringElement ("Value1", "Aligned on each side", UITableViewCellStyle.Value1),
new StyledStringElement ("Value2", "Like the Addressbook", UITableViewCellStyle.Value2),
new StyledStringElement ("Subtitle", "Makes it sound more important", UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle),
new StyledStringElement ("Subtitle", "Brown subtitle", UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle) {
    DetailColor = UIColor.Brown
}
```

See the [MT.Dialog sample app](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/Sample/DemoStyled.cs) for an example of this code in action.